# Is there a chance to check which applications are deployed on an Apache Server

Tags: apache

If so, how?

And how to check wether they are running?

Is there something like the manager for tomcat?

I have an Apache Server running, that has been installed automatically by a package installation routine. I expect that the routine installed OpenProject on the server. But I cannot point to the application.

So I don't know wether OpenProject is not installed, not started or pointing to it with

http://185.82.22.144:80/OpenProject

is wrong.

The installation routine seemed to work fine, with no error messages.

peter

Answer (score 0):

No, because the way you are using language implies that you are asking about functionality which is exposed by the Apache server - but that functionality is not "in" the webserver, apache merely provides a means for accessing it.